# How can I change one object only when one other object is selected?

Tags: if-statement, expression, selection, maya, mel

I'm browsing MEL and expressions and trying to do something like this: if I select one object I deactivate one property from another. But I'm having problems with the object selection denomination. The following is an example:

```
If (select pCube1-r on) {
      PCube2.visibility = 0;
}
```

I have tried with strings too but it didn't work...

```
global proc myscript() {
    string $a[] = ls -sl;
    if ($a[0] == "pCube1")
        hide = "pCube2";
    else;
}
```

scriptJob -e"SelectionChanged"
    "myScript";

Can someone help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a given object is selected you'll need to loop over the list returned by `ls -sl`.

```
string $sel[] = `ls -sl`;
string $item;
for ($item in $sel)
{
    if ($item == "your-object-here")
    {
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

This is safer than using an index in any case because you can't be sure there will be an item 0.

Comment: Hi man, I have tried and worked It!!! Thank you!! But I still have a problem... Just worked Once ... I want everytime the selection is changed the expression should execute...

Comment: string $sel[] = `ls -sl`;
     string $item;
      for ($item in $sel)
       {
           if ($item == "pCube1")
            {
               pCube2.translateX = 15;
            }
        if ($item == "pCube3")
            {
               pCube2.translateX = 25;
            }
       }

Comment: If I try with scripts it doesn´t appear error messages too , but it doesn´t work...                                                                                                global proc myScript()
{
 string $sel[] = `ls -sl`;
 string $item;
  for ($item in $sel)
   {
       if ($item == "pCube1")
        {
           pCube2.translateX = 15;
        }
    if ($item == "pCube3")
        {
           pCube2.translateX = 25;
        }
   }
}


scriptJob -e"SelectionChanged"
"myScript";